# Matching between two arrays in excel and then outputting a value

Tags: excel

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7BTd.png)

So I have a situation where I want to match the values in A2:A4 with the values in B2:F4 and then output the values in B5:F5 in cell A5 (depending on which column is matched). So in this particular case, the values in column A match the values in column E so the output in A5 should be 1. I want an Excel formula that will do this for me (no VBA). Can someone kindly help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please elabore more examples

Answer (score 0):

```
B5  =IF(A2=B2&A3=B3&A4=B4,1,0)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.